# set activated state for shape android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Layout in my app which I defined as:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/amountLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_effect_green"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp" >
```

and `gradient_effect_green` is:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<
<solid android:color="@color/green_light" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:topRightRadius="20dp" /></shape>
```

Everything is working like a charm. Now I want to set listener on this layout and I want to define activated state for this layout, but I do not know how. By activated state I mean for example change the background color when user touches this layout. Something like this:

```
android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/deep_light"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow the steps

**1) gradient_effect_green.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<
<solid android:color="@color/green_light" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:topRightRadius="20dp" /></shape>
```

**2) gradient_effect_green_selected.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <
    <solid android:color="@color/deep_light" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp" /></shape>
```

**3) gradient_effect_selector.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_effect_green_selected" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_effect_green_selected" android:state_focused="true"></item>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_effect_green" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"></item>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_effect_green_selected" android:state_enabled="false"></item>

</selector>
```

**4) your_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/amountLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_effect_selector" // CHANGE HERE
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp" >
```